# Using JUnit 5 to test transform

Tags: apache-beam

We are using JUnit 5 in a new project, and it has removed support for `@Rule` I would like to know:

1. Why do the current unit tests use `@Rule` on the `TestPipeline`?
2. Is there a JUnit 5 alternative extension?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam [currently depends on](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/dd2f67bb8ec49e542635035743a754421cce3a75/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/beam/gradle/BeamModulePlugin.groovy#L595) JUnit 4.13.0.

Feel free to [create a JIRA](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) to address this. Any [contributions](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/) related to this are welcome as well.